# Replacing spaces with underscores (ignore spaces that beginning or end of the string)

Tags: perl

I got below code that able to replace spaces to underscore.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    

my $subject ="FD 2000k";

print "Before - $subject\n";
#Result : Before - FD 2000k    
$subject =~ tr/ /_/;

print "After - $subject\n";
#Result : After - FD_2000k
```

However, if the `$subject` consists of space at the end of `FD 2000k` and the result will be `After - FD_2000K_`. Refer to below code.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;  

#Note: Behind 2000k got space
my $subject ="FD 2000k ";

print "Before - $subject\n";
#Result : Before - FD 2000k    
$subject =~ tr/ /_/;

print "After - $subject\n";
#Result : After - FD_2000k_
```

Anyone know how to ignore the spaces that appear on the beginning or end of the string?

Expected result : Ignore the spaces that before or after string, just replace the spaces that in the "middle" of the string. Result should be `FD_2000k` instead of `FD_2000k_`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substitution:

```
$subject =~  s/(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)/_/g;
```

This will replace spaces only if they are preceeded and followed by a word character.

You could also use:

```
 $subject =~  s/(?<!^)\s(?!$)/_/g;
```

This will replace spaces only if they aren't at the begining or at the end of the string.

Comment: Hi! hmm, any modules require? I mean `Use ...` . As I get error said that `Sequence (?<\...) not recognized in regex`

Comment: @thor_that_new_in_programming: Sorry, I've forgotten an `=` sign. See my edit